# Tracking Logged on Users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

On a project I'm building for a client, one of the requirements is advanced user tracking.  The client would like to know what pages an authenticated user is visiting, and when.  I read through [this post](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Tracking-User-Activity.aspx), which is probably the method I will go with.  However, that seems a bit tolling on the database, and being that the client may use Azure to host this, I would like to keep the # of db transactions to a minimum [although this was not one of his requirements...  just a favor i guess :) ].  Anyway, I'm torn between the following two methods...  please advise what you all feel is best and what the pros / cons of either method might be.  Or suggest any alternative methods I may have missed.

1. Method One: Log to db on every HTTP request using a HTTP module
2. Method Two: Store in visits in session and log everything to database in one swoop during Session_End event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premature optimization is the root of most evil. I would personally say option 1, since it should be the simplest to implement.

For your own satisfaction, you might consider the cost of a database hit, how many you're already making during a request, and then how many you would be expecting to get, say, per day. (And then compare it to how much *your* time costs...)

From glancing at the Azure stuff, it appears that the cost will be negligible unless you end up with a titanic amount of traffic. I can't really understand what the charts mean, but I'm assuming the cost is either 15 cents per gigabyte of transfer, or a 14 GB block of transfer per month, which really is a lot in terms of sending database rows.

Comment: Yeah, it's not astronomical.  It is 1 cent for every 10k transactions.  So customer will be charged .000001 cent every time a user makes a request using Method 1, which is probably a lot smaller of a charge than my hourly rate to build the session stuff.  Therefore, I'm going to side with your advice.  It is probably not worth the time and hours needed to build a session based alternative.